# deprecated dynamic property: "archiveName" on "source set 'war'"

Tags: groovy, gradle

I wrote gradle plugin which configures a war project, when it is applied. My question deals with the configuration of the war task. I want to change the archiveName and the classpath.

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.plugins.apply('war')
        // do something
        configureConfigurations(project)
        configureTask(project)
    }
    void configureTask(final Project project) {
        project.war {
            archiveName = "${project.war.baseName}.${project.war.extension}"
            classpath = project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath - project.configurations.providedRuntime - project.configurations.earModuleRuntime - project.configurations.earLibRuntime
        }
        project.war {
            doFirst {
                // just generating the manifest file
            }
        }
    }

    void configureConfigurations(final Project project) {
        project.configurations {
            earModuleCompile
            earModuleRuntime.extendsFrom(earModuleCompile)
            earLibCompile
            earLibRuntime.extendsFrom(earLibCompile)
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason gradle interprets the first war block as a source set. That is why it creates a new property called archiveName and classpath on a source set 'war'. I can fix it with `project.war.archiveName`. But I still have no clue why on earth gradle things the first war block is a source set and the second one with `doFirst` is the task.

The build file which uses this plugin does only define some dependencies on `earLibRuntime`

It would be nice if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: It's impossible to explain this without knowing the context. (A regular build won't even have a source set named `war`.) Does your plugin apply the `war` plugin? Otherwise, it cannot assume that there will be a `war` task. A safer way for a plugin to access a task is `project.tasks["taskName"]`.

Comment: Sorry missed that line. yes it applies the war plugin, but it never introduces a source set called war. I can assure you that there is nothing happening that would interfere with the war plunin.

Comment: Hard to imagine. To investigate further, I'd need a self-contained reproducible example.

Comment: Ok I start to believe that I might accidentally add a source set war, but I still have no idea where. But even so, why should gradle try to call `archiveName` on that source set? Aren't source sets only reachable with `project.sourceSets.war`?

Comment: Yes. Chances are that something is wrong with your build script or plugin code.